# How to look for a specific string after a matched string from a file using sed, awk or grep

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, rhel

Sample of output stored in a file:

```
Provides:        Red Hat Satellite
                 Red Hat Developer Toolset (for RHEL Server)
  SKU:                 TGV123
  Contract:            59104
  Pool ID:             abcdxyz12340987
```

From the above output, I want to look for "Red Hat Satellite" and look for the line containing "Pool ID:" so that I get the value of the pool ID i.e. abcdxyz12340987.

How can I obtain this using sed, awk or grep? "Pool ID" may appear several lines after "Red Hat Satellite" i.e. no set number of lines in between them.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: is there a set range of lines between them? There's better awk solutions out there, but here's something dirty:
`grep -A10 "Provides:        Red Hat Satellite" file | grep "Pool ID:" | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'`     just change "A10" to the maximum amount of lines there is between the `Provides` line and the `Pool ID` line

Comment: @RobotJohnny, the lines vary, hence wanted something which will be independent of lines in between. The solutions below work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n '/Red Hat Satellite/,/Pool ID:/{ s/.*Pool ID:[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)/\1/p; }' file
```

This applies a substitution that picks out your string from after `Pool ID:`. It does this on any line between a line that contains the string `Red Hat Satellite` and the first line afterwards that contain `Pool ID:`.  The command would print only the result of any successful substitution.

The following `awk` command would do the same, provided that the string at the end of the `Pool ID:` line does not contain any whitespace:

```
awk '/Red Hat Satellite/,/Pool ID:/ { if (/Pool ID:/) print $NF }' file
```

`grep` would not be the tool for this job as it is bad at handling context ("extract one line given some match on another line"). It would possibly work given some PCRE over nul-terminated lines using GNU `grep`, but it would be a hack.

Comment: If string Pool ID happened to be on the same line as the red hat line, then the awk solution wouldn't work. Range operators in sed n awk r different in where they test for the conditions.

Comment: @RakeshSharma This is true. It would not work for any provider whose name contains the string `Pool ID:`.

Comment: @RakeshSharma they will always been on different lines. So no worries on that!

Comment: @Kusalananda, thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

With **`awk`** scripting:

```
$ awk '/Red Hat Satellite/{ f=1; next }f && /Pool ID:/{ print $NF; exit }' yourfile
abcdxyz12340987
```

Comment: This one works as well. Thanks!